# Button won't change background on click

Tags: android, button, colors, onclick

I have three `Buttons`. I want the button to change color on click, and then if I click on the button again it goes back to the default color.

Problem: If I click on the first one, it will change color. However if I click on the second one, it will not change color. But if I click on that second `Button` an additional time it will finally change color. Does anyone know why the second `Button` won't change color on the first click?

Note: After debugging I noticed that the `is_clicked` is set to 1 after I click on the first `Button`. So when I click on the second `Button`, it thinks it has already changed color and sets it back to default. Does anyone know how I can properly set the `is_clicked` flag? Or is there something else I should do?

```
 int is_clicked = 0;


 public void ButtonOnClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
              case R.id.button1:
                  if (is_clicked == 1){
                      button_list.get(0).getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x00000000));;
                      is_clicked--;
                      break;
                  }
                  if (is_clicked == 0){
                      button_list.get(0).getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFF00FF00));
                      is_clicked++;
                      break;
                  }
                      break;
              case R.id.button2:
                  if (is_clicked == 1){
                      button_list.get(1).getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x00000000));;
                      is_clicked--;
                      break;
                  }
                  if (is_clicked == 0){
                      button_list.get(1).getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFF00FF00));
                      is_clicked++;
                      break;
                  }
                      break;
              case R.id.button3:
                  if (is_clicked == 1){
                      button_list.get(2).getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x00000000));;
                      is_clicked--;
                      break;
                  }
                  if (is_clicked == 0){
                      button_list.get(2).getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFF00FF00));
                      is_clicked++;
                      break;
                  }
                      break;
               }
           }
```

Comment: Then Have three int is_clicked Like btn1_clicked,btn2_clicked,btn3_clicked

Comment: hm, good proposal. However in my program I actually have 50 buttons. So I was hoping I could use one is_clicked for all cases. I just shortened it to three buttons for this example and simplicity...

Comment: Its a bad practice to set the colors like that, why u don't use `Selector` instead, you can achieve this just by 2 or 3 line of codes

Comment: I have never used Selector before. Would you be able to show me if it's only a few lines of code?

Comment: @user2456977 of course, I added a bit of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with Pedram.... As per your request, You use tags in xml.

Put this tag in each button

```
     android:tag="0"
```

In case

```
  String clicked= (String)btn1.getTag();
  If ("0".equals(clicked)) {
     //set a color for your button
      button1.setTag("1");
   } else {
    //set a color for your button
      button1.setTag("0");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its just a simple button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>

</selector>
```

Set this as your button's background

**Edits:** The last one is default, there are more state also, like selected and disable, try to play with them, you can make lots of functionality with selectors.

This one is a nice button. with stroke and disable state.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
      <solid
          android:color="#00aeef" />
      <stroke
          android:width="1dp"
          android:color="#0090bf" />
      <corners
          android:radius="6dp" />
      <padding
          android:left="10dp"
          android:top="10dp"
          android:right="10dp"
          android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
<!--     #ef4444  #992f2f -->
</item>
  <item android:state_enabled="false">
      <shape>
      <solid
          android:color="#174574"/>
      <stroke
          android:width="1dp"
          android:color="#12375D" />
      <corners
          android:radius="6dp" />
      <padding
          android:left="10dp"
          android:top="10dp"
          android:right="10dp"
          android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
<!--   Default -->
  <item>
    <shape>
      <gradient
          android:startColor="#3399FF"
          android:endColor="#2E8AE6"
          android:angle="270" />
      <stroke
          android:width="1dp"
          android:color="#297CCF" />
      <corners
          android:radius="6dp" />
      <padding
          android:left="10dp"
          android:top="10dp"
          android:right="10dp"
          android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Sorry, I am a little new to this. Which folder/file do I add this in? Do I create a new xml file in drawable? or do I add this in the layour xml where I created the buttons?

Comment: @user2456977 put it in your drawable folder, if you don't have it already create a new one, and get rid of all the switch case code also, it just works through XML.

Comment: I had to chose Indra's answer since Indra answered it using my current code. However I will probably change my code the way you suggested. But I gave you an upvote at least :) Thanks so much!

Comment: hm, in this code it changes color only when I press it. Once I let go it goes back to default. I want the color to be changed also when I let go... any ideas?

Comment: As I said there is more sates in selectors, Use the one that suits your needs, head to docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64427/discussion-between-user2456977-and-pedram).